# How to include all pages except last one from an external PDF

Tags: pdfpages

I'm using the package `pdfpages` to insert (many) external PDFs in my pdflatex compiled document, but I need to insert separately *`all the pages but the last one`* and the *`last page`* (I have to issue some commands in between). It seems that the `pages` option of `includepdf` command hasn't a direct way to do it.

I tried using `\the\pdflastximagepages` but I'm not good enough at LaTeX to deploy it for this task. Thanks in advance for any clue.

Here is a MWE to work on.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\pdfximage{test.pdf}
\def\lastbutonepage{3}% set for testing purpose assuming 'test.pdf' has 4 pages

\ifnum\lastbutonepage>0
\includepdf[pages=-\lastbutonepage]{test.pdf}
\fi
Something in between.
\includepdf[pages=\the\pdflastximagepages]{test.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I store the last page (number) as well as the page before that in `\totalpages` and `\lastbutonepage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\pdfximage{example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}% Read entire PDF
\edef\totalpages{\the\pdflastximagepages}% Store number of pages
\edef\lastbutonepage{\number\numexpr\totalpages-1}% Store last page - 1

\ifnum\totalpages>1
  \includepdf[pages=1-\lastbutonepage]{example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}%
\fi
Something in the middle.

\includepdf[pages=\totalpages]{example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice to know. Just wondering, why do you need the `\number` in that definition?

Comment: @daleif: Without it, `\lastbutonepage` isn't properly expanded to just contain the *result* of the numeric expression. As such, it's carried forward to the optional argument of `\includepdf` and it doesn't like that.

Comment: Thanks, I would have thought edef took care of that, I was mistaken.